# Understanding the behavior of Conflict Serializability and View Serializability with respect to blind writes

Tags: database-theory

I have seen that most standard college textbooks of Database Management Systems use this method to classify whether a schedule is view serializable or not.

[image]

I know the definitions of Conflict Serializability and View Serializability, but I am unable to think of a generalized proof that the above flowchart is actually correct.

I first tried to prove (or get an intuition) of the right side of the above diagram, when the schedule is not conflict serializable, and the absence of blind writes ensures nonview serializability. Also, tried to make out what change is caused when we have a blind write in the same situation that the schedule now might be view serializable? But always I end up with a specific example, namely this:

[image]

Which is non-conflict serializable due to the presence of cycle between nodes T1 and T2 in the precedence graph but it is view serializable and it has blind writes...

Can anyone help me intuition or proof?